# How to make typedoc works with deno

Tags: deno, typedoc

I am using Deno in one of my projects and I want to generate the documentation with typedoc. I am facing a lot of problems with dependencies because they do not get resolved correctly, so typedoc fails. I have the following `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "target": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "http://*": ["../../../.deno/deps/http/*"],
      "https://*": ["../../../.deno/deps/https/*"],
      "*.ts": ["*"]
    },
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-deno-plugin"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The first two entries in `paths` resolve the native modules of Deno (like its assertion library). The problem comes when I use another library like Cheerio, importing it like this in my `deps.ts` file:

```
// @deno-types="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/justjavac/deno_cheerio/cheerio.d.ts"
import cheerio from "https://dev.jspm.io/cheerio/index";
```

Note: I have to import the types from an external source because the types declared in dev.jspm.io do not work because they include the `/// reference` directive.

I have the following `typedoc.js` config file:

```
// deno-lint-ignore-file
module.exports = {
  out: "./docs-build",
  mode: "file",
};
```

If I run `typedoc src/`, I get the following error:

```
Using TypeScript 4.0.3 from /home/antonio/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.1/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib
Error: /home/antonio/manga-api/src/deps.ts(8)
 Cannot find module 'https://dev.jspm.io/cheerio/index'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?
```

Note2: I'm using deno but `typedoc` is installed with npm globally, along `typescript` and `typescript-deno-plugin`.

Any idea how to make `typedoc` work correctly with Deno?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get TypeDoc working (at least with a simple library) by performing these steps.

Output Deno's types so TypeDoc can find them.

```
deno types > deno.d.ts
```

Add a `tsconfig.json` file based on [Deno's implied `tsconfig.json`](https://deno.land/manual@v1.36.4/advanced/typescript/configuration#what-an-implied-tsconfigjson-looks-like) file, then remove `lib` and set `allowImportingTsExtensions`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true
  }
}
```

Add a `typedoc.json` file with `entryPoints` and `skipErrorChecking` set.

```json
{
  "entryPoints": ["./mod.ts"],
  "skipErrorChecking": true
}
```

Alternatively run TypeDoc with with the `--skipErrorChecking` flag and provide the entry points.

```
typedoc --skipErrorChecking ./mod.ts
```

This worked with the following versions:

- Deno: 1.36.1
- TypeDoc: 0.25.0

Answer (score 0):

Typedoc won't work with Deno. Deno supports module resolution and URL resolution, which Node (the current runtime for Typedoc) lacks of. The only way it could work is if Typedoc itself run in Deno, but it doesn't offer support for it at the moment.

Comment: Hum, there has to be a way to make it work. I will mark this as correct in a week or so just in case someone knows how to fix it. Do you know another way of generating a HTML documentation for Deno?

Comment: @AntonioGamizDelgado https://deno.land/manual@v1.4.6/tools/documentation_generator. Comes integrated with Deno. I think there is a third party lib that allows you to turn that into HTML files

Comment: I know that, what I don't know is that third party lib.